# conditional jade, DOM object values

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

The following is an excerpt from a Jade template

```
        .row
            .col-xs-2
            -if(message.length>0)
                .alert.alert-danger.col-xs-4
```

**1.** I'm trying to have the conditional but have it on the same level as the .col-xs-2 div, not inside it. Is there a way to do this?

**2.** How do I give the .alert div the Value of the message string in the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is what you're looking for.

```
    .row
        if(message.length>0)
            .col-xs-2      
                .alert.alert-danger.col-xs-4 #{message}
```

You may need this instead though for the alert:

```
                .alert.alert-danger.col-xs-4= message
```